# Double motion of bone if its parent is another bone

Tags: animation, rigging

Trying to creat a rig where a have a simple motion  of leg with local upvectors for roll. Problem is taht I need (green) bone to be the chiled bone of "Body" bone for export animation purpose. But move with IK control and completely linked to it.. If I child of contrain the "green bone" it works perfect... Until I move whole body.. Then child bone just doubles the transform and geen bone flyis double the distance..
https://i.postimg.cc/ZKDXHsmF/blender-lvmi-Sysp-UO.gif

I guess I'm missing something.. Is there some kind of visual constrain solution for this? Or am doing it wrong from the start?